# How to BSWAP the lower 32-bit of 64-bit register?

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, endianness

I've been looking for the answer for how to use BSWAP for lower 32-bit sub-register of 64-bit register. For example, `0x0123456789abcdef` is inside RAX register, and I want to change it to `0x01234567efcdab89` with a single instruction (because of performance).

So I tried following inline function:

```c
#define BSWAP(T) {  \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (  \
            "bswap %k0" \
            : "=q" (T)  \
            : "q" (T)); \
}
```

And the result was `0x00000000efcdab89`. I don't understand why the compiler acts like this. Does anybody know the efficient solution?

Comment: Down-voting for overuse of question marks

Comment: Replaced `64-bit` tag with `64bit`, because there are more questions tagged `64bit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, yes, I understand the problem now:

the x86-64 processors *[implicitly zero-extend](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html)* the 32-bit registers to 64-bit when doing 32-bit operations (on %eax, %ebx, etc).  This is to maintain compatibility with legacy code that expects 32-bit semantics for these registers, as I understand it.

So I'm afraid that there is **no way** to do `ror` on just the lower 32 bits of a 64-bit register.  You'll have to do use a series of several instructions...

Comment: [Why do most x64 instructions zero the upper part of a 32 bit register](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137/995714)

Answer (score -1):

Check the assembly output generated by gcc!  Use the `gcc -s` flag to compile the code and generate asm output.

IIRC, x86-64 uses 32-bit integers by default when not explicitly directed to do otherwise, so this may be (part of) the problem.