# Reverse 4 bytes using inline assembly

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I know how to do it in C,
and I know how to do it in assembly.
But I never did inline assembly before.
How could I do it in inline assembly?

Comment: If you know how to do this in assembly then you know how to do it in inline assembly; the only difference is that the latter appears within a program written in some higher-level language. I presume that is C in your case? What have you tried? What's going wrong?

Comment: With most compilers, you *shouldn't* use inline asm.  Use an intrinsic instead so the compiler can do constant-propagation.  Also, so it can choose between `bswap reg` vs. `movbe reg, [mem]` vs. `movbe [mem], reg`, if we're talking about x86 where there are multiple efficient ways.

Comment: Anyway, which compiler are you using, and which architecture?  There are two major flavours of inline-asm syntax: MSVC (where single instructions are impossible to do efficiently) vs. GNU (where you need to accurately describe the asm to the compiler by telling it which registers and memory locations are inputs / outputs / clobbers.)  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Comment: I'm using GCC on x86. I haven't used inline assembly before, so I don't know how to convert my assembly to inline assembly.

Comment: What's wrong with gcc's [__builtin_bswap32](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fbswap32)?  As a general rule, I'd recommend [not using inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  But if you must, have you read gcc's [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for inline asm?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Comment: I improved the question format and some grammar.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [How to make GCC generate bswap instruction for big endian store without builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36497605), but the inline-asm answer there is not good.  [How to BSWAP the lower 32-bit of 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176966) has the answer to this as part of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to BSWAP the lower 32-bit of 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176966/how-to-bswap-the-lower-32-bit-of-64-bit-register)